# Parsing XML from php using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I have a script in php that writes XML.

I use an ajax call to read that XML.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://blablabla.com/myscript.php",
        data: requestVars,
        dataType: 'xml',
        success: function(xml){
            XMLParser(xml);
            },
        error: function(xhr,err){
            alert("readyState: "+ xhr.readyState + "\nstatus: " + xhr.status + "\nerror:" + err);
            alert("responseText: " + xhr.responseText);
            }
    });
```

On php I have this:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8');

...
?>
```

(tried both with application/xml and text/xml)

Problem:

Works like a charm in Google Chrome, fails on IE9 and Firefox with readyState: 4, status: 200 and Error: parsererror

EDIT:
A little piece of sample XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>

    <Index Title="asdsad" isImg="0">
      <Categories>
        <Cat Id="13">
          <Title>Movies</Title>
        </Cat>
        <Cat Id="15">
          <Title>Books</Title>
        </Cat>
      </Categories>
      <Subject Id="141" Open="0">
        <Title>Subject A</Title>
        <Resource Id="553" Level="2">
          <Title>Resource A1</Title>
        </Resource>
        </Subject>
    </Index>
```

Comment: Can you show us the XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that your editor setup encode is utf-8 and you save this xml/php file as utf-8?

Use firebug into firefox to check what error is generating your call. Maybe is just some not valid utf-8 character inside your xml.

Comment: I've checked and the php is in utf-8. But using fiddler2 and firebug i saw that there are certain characters that are not correctly encoded ... i don't know why. Maybe you're right, but i can't find the problem

Comment: @jose: as i said before be sure your editor/ide or what else you use to program got character encoding as utf-8, you should find this under general settings. If some chars are NOT utf-8 may be caused by some data arriving from the db/file or dunno what you are parsing to get this xml generated.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that jQuery is unable to parse the XML, but your XMLParser might be.

If that is the case, you can process any result you get with the `complete` function. It will be called whether or not there is an error (network error *or* parsing error).

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/